# ¿Es necesario bloquear una tabla si realizo una Transacción?

Tags: mysql, transacciones

Estoy trabajando en una Base de datos MySql y debo realizar una transacción pero me surge la duda si debo o no bloquear las tablas que entran en dicha operación, alguien podría orientarme. Esta demás decir que soy algo novato en esto.
De antemano Gracias

Comment: Lo que preguntas es extremadamente amplio y depende muchas circunstancias. Quizás lo primero sería preguntarse que es un bloqueo y si lo necesito.

Comment: Me refiero al bloqueo de la tabla ya sea para escritura o lectura, en este caso para escribir sobre la tabla+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grandes rasgos: Una transacción inicia una vida paralela en la base de datos. Todo lo que hagas, será únicamente visto por tu proceso.
Para terminar la transacción, tienes dos opciones: rollback (deshace todos los cambios) o commit (haces que los cambios sean definitivos y afectan, por tanto, a todos los demás procesos.

No es necesario bloquear tablas para trabajar con transacciones

Comment: Gracias por la información